# PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick

The following error occured when try to query a list of email with provided email,password. Actually the **subscribers_table** has 10 columns with column names of **email** and **password**.

```
[PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.]
```

**My LoginProcess Model code:**

```
    case class LoginProcess(email:String,password:String)

    //error occured in this line
    implicit val getLoginProcessResult = GetResult(r => LoginProcess(r.nextString, r.nextString))

    def check_Login_Success_Query(email: String,password:String) = sql"select email from provisions_schema.subscribers_table where email = $email and password=$password ".as[LoginProcess]

    val login_Success_Query_List = check_Login_Success_Query(email_ip,password_ip).list

    println("login_Success_Query_List.length ->" +login_Success_Query_List.length)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this:

```
select email from provisions_schema.subscribers_table
```

And the model expects `email` and `password`. Add the password to your query

Comment: No.Same error occurs after adding "select email,password from ..."

Comment: sorry i add single quotes to where condition parameters.After removing single quotes it works fine.